# how can I remove a pattern from the begining of lines between two words using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to remove a pattern in the begining of each line of a paragraph that contains word1 in the first line and end with word2 for example if I have the following file and I want to subsitute --MW by nothing

```
--MW Word1 this is paragraph number 1 
--MW aaa
--MW bbb
--MW ccc
--MW word2
```

I want to get as result :

```
Word1 this is paragraph number 1 
aaa
bbb
ccc
word2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `begins with word1` it begins with `--MW`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed '/Word1/,/word2/s/--MW //' file
```

Using awk

```
awk '/Word1/,/word2/{sub(/--MW /,a)}1' file
```

Both act on lines between and including the matched phrases and the do a substitution on each line. They print all lines.

Comment: I like this one. Didn't know about the range. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Component10 Yeah, your solution using flags is normally better though for anything but trivial problems. This just looks neater for simple ones :)

Comment: Personally I find the use of an uninitialized variable like `a` instead of what you really mean/need (i.e. `""`) just obfuscates the code and leaves it open to future breakage if/when you introduce a variable named `a` elsewhere in your code, not sure what the point is of doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton Dunno i suppose i think it looks nicer for basic examples like this. Feel free to edit it though if you think it is promoting bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your text in `myfile.txt` you could try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=0}$2=="Word1"{f=1}{if (f==1) {$1="";print $0}else{print $0}}$2=="word2"{f=0}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't remove the --MW from the begining of each line

Comment: `awk '$2=="Word1"{f=1}f==1{$1=""}$2=="word2"{f=0}1'`

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me.

Comment: Either way, personally, I prefer 123's solution and I would go with that.

Comment: While that would delete the `--MW`, it'd leave the blank char after it and it'd also change all tabs and other chains of white space to blank chars which would probably be undesirable. This is a good approach but you need to write it as `awk '$2=="Word1"{f=1} f{sub(/^--MW[[:space:]]+/,"")} $2=="word2"{f=0} 1'` to be robust and have no unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the pattern is going to be in the beginning of the line, then this command might help:

```
sed 's/^--MW //' file.txt
```

Please test and let us know if this worked fine with you.

Comment: yes but that command edit the whole file I want to change a specific paragraph

Comment: sure, sec, I'll give you the next fix

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will do it for you:

```
$ echo "--MW Word1 this is paragraph number 1" | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Where you pass the text to cut command and remove the first token, using space as token separator, while keeping the rest of tokens,i.e., from second to the end.